# "mysql -v" command line error(linux/ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, command-line, bitnami

```
bitnami@ip-10-99-67-123:~/.rvm/gems$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

bitnami@ip-10-99-67-123:~/.rvm/gems$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.3

bitnami@ip-10-99-67-123:~/.rvm/gems$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.22, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

bitnami@ip-10-99-67-123:~/.rvm/gems$ mysql -v
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
bitnami@ip-10-99-67-123:~/.rvm/gems$
```

Any Idea why this is happening?

I only got an error on `mysql -v` command

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   ·   --verbose, -v

       Verbose mode. Produce more output about what the program does. This option can be given multiple times to produce more and more output. (For example, -v -v -v produces table output format even in
       batch mode.)

   ·   --version, -V

       Display version information and exit.
```

what you want ? verbose or version ?

if you want server side version, connect to server, send query `status;`

You should connect server with full args, example:

```
> mysql --user=user --password=password --host=serverip
```

or put the args on `~/.my.cnf`

just like mine:

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
prompt="\\u@\\h \\r:\\m:\\s > "
user=user
password=DqvQ86ls1VQit617C
host=127.0.0.1
port=3306
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried it and I still got an error `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'rocksuper.bitnamiapp.com' (110)` 
any suggestion?

Comment: search keyword "mysql error 2003", you will got http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html
how about your /etc/my.cnf, you sure it started ?

Comment: when I try to `service mysql start` It gives me a msg that says: `start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.61" (uid=1000 pid=22761 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")` Wonder why?, Any Idea?

Comment: It is running now but, the socket is not there. in `/var/run/mysqld/` directory there is no `mysqld.sock`. How do I recover or generate the mysqld.sock?... Thank you

Comment: `/etc/mysql/my.ini` or connect it with hostname `mysql --user... --host=localhost --port=3306`

Comment: You asked too many questions in comment, accept the answer first, you can post a new question "how to connect mysql server with socket"