# MySQL User Permission Errors using Sqitch on Ubtunu

Tags: mysql, sqitch

I am running into what I think is a very easy issue to fix, I am just out of possible ideas.

I have a brand new Ubuntu 14.04 x64 server. I just installed MySQL. Not Apache, php or phpMyAdmin, just plain MySQL.

I have run through `mysql_secure_installation` and created a password for my root user.

I then put my root password in the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file under the `[client]` section.

I can run `mysql -u root` and get to the MySQL console just fine.

However, if I run `sqitch deploy` I get:
`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Sqitch is pointing to:

```
[target "database name_v1"]
uri = db:mysql://root@/databasename_v1
[engine "mysql"]
target = db:mysql://root@/databasename_v1
```

EDIT

It turns out the problem was with Sqitch and my configuration. Sqitch is a Perl application and needed the perl module MySQL Config in order to read the my.cnf file and access the database.

Comment: One of them is connecting you thru the socket while the other is connecting thru tcp port. If you specify `-S /path/to/socket` or `-h hostname -P portnumber`, whichever works, use it on both `mysql -u root` and `mysql -v ` and you will get a consistent connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with Sqitch and my configuration. Sqitch is a Perl application and needed the perl module [MySQL::Config](https://metacpan.org/pod/MySQL::Config) in order to read the `my.cnf` file and access the database.

Comment: Consider accepting this answer if it fixed your issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `-v` to get MySQL version, here's your answer : **`mysql -V`**

-v is for *verbose* output.

See this thread for more details.
["mysql -v" command line error(linux/ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612251/mysql-v-command-line-errorlinux-ubuntu)

Comment: No. This is not related what so ever. Why can I login to the console just fine, but when running other commands it denies me access and is NOT using the password set in my.cnf, which is obviously working when it is letting me into the console.

Comment: I don't have much clues then.  I never had any problem using .my.cnf.  The only difference I see so far is that I use [mysql] instead of [client], but I doubt this could be the cause, since [client] seems more permissive. (
cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453555/mysql-configuration-file-sections )
I assume you run both commands in the exact same conditions ? In that case, I really have no idea atm, sorry :|

Comment: @Balmipour - it is obvious that the OP has the correct user, otherwise the error message will not be for user `root@localhost`.

Comment: @user1302023 I don't know sqitch at all, but to me, the problem seems to be on that side.  What if you specify to use user "foobar" instead of root in .my.cnf ? I'd bet you'll still get "Access denied for user 'root'".
Btw, did you try alvits's suggestion ?  It seemed improbable to me on a fresh install, but in such cases, checking won't hurt
Also try commenting `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` if necessary.  I already have had problems with local services using "distant" connections, on odd configurations.

Comment: @balmipour Updating my questiion now. It was a sqitch issue. Sqitch is a PERL app and it needed a perl module called MySQL Config installed to allow it to read the my.cnf file.

Comment: @user1302023 Glad to see it's solved.
Since your problem seems to be a basic config error, it would be good to mark the question as answered, so that other users may find it (and make the title a little more clear, e.g., appending "when using sqitch deploy")
Since we mainly talked in comments, and my first answer wasn't the solution, you have two possibilities : post yourself an answer and accept it, or ask me to post one, if you think I helped you enough to deserve the credits.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple root users in mysql. They are in the format `user@remote`.

You can check if the user password is set for all of those by running the query `select Host, User, Password from mysql.user where User="root";`

The output should show something like:

```
+--------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| Host         | User     | Password                                  |
+--------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost    | root     | *XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |
| testvm       | root     | *XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |
| 127.0.0.1    | root     | *XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX |
```

If the password is empty, set it via `mysqladmin`.

From here on, your connection to mysql, whether coming from localhost, or coming from the hostname will be allowed to login.